# Run a CODEUNIT via NAS, containing a function from FORM object?

Tags: navision

Is it possible to run a CODEUNIT via NAS (Navision Application Server) while the codeunit itself contains a function from FORM object?

P.S.: Navision version: 2009 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to run code on NAS as long as this code doesn't actually call form functions. E.g., the following code is fine for NAS:

```
IF GUIALLOWED THEN
  MyForm.SomeFunction();
```

But you will not be able to run function from a form even if it contains only non-GUI-specific logic. This is one of the reasons not to put any business logic on forms :)

The same rule goes to NAV Server and Web Services. Form (and dataport) objects are not being translated to C#, so it is not possible to run code from a form or dataport.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what is the connection between C# translation and NAS Server?

Comment: There is no connection, my comment regarding C# translation was related only to NAV Server/WebServices (and their own inability to run code from forms), so you may totally disregard it :)